# Create individual timer to activate after few minute

Tags: c#, timer

its that possible that i can create a individual timer for different situation?

For example i got 3 different label, by the time i right click it show menustrip with "Acknowledge". First i wan to change active to NO and after certain timing i change it back to YES.

```
void contexMenuuu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if (item.Text == "Acknowledge")
        {
            label.Text = "NO";

            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            int _timeinverval = 5; //mins
            aTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_timeinverval).TotalMilliseconds;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;

        }
}

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    label.Text = "YES"// update after 5min 
}
```

What i have to do with the 'OnTimedEvent' if i wan to change the active back to 'YES' after 5mins?

Comment: Does the code work ??

Comment: @KcDoD Hi, what I able to do now was for one label only if i use a counter to do all this. When i click on the second label the counter will be reset.  And what i need now was create individual timer for each label. Its that possible we can get the timer tick count?

Comment: Just a code comment: instead of doing the math in your code to calculate how many miliseconds are in 5 minutes, consider making your code more readable by using the TimeSpan class instead: `aTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds;`

Comment: you can do that with even only one timer considering the object you have to work with, you know it at the timer event. . ..

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me what exactly the question is here. The code you posted won't actually work (you can't update the `Text` property from a timer callback, unless the timer is `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which it's not here). And you use variables `item` and `label` which aren't declared in the code example.

That said, based on the more general description of what you seem to want to do, then if you are using .NET 4.5 you probably should skip the timer and just use `async`/`await`:

```
async void contexMenuuu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ... something here?;
    var label = ... and something here?;

    if (item.Text == "Acknowledge")
    {
        label.Text = "NO";
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        label.Text = "YES";
    }
}
```

Much simpler. :)

If you're not using .NET 4.5, then taking a guess as to what the real question is here, I'm going to assume the problem you are having is that `label` is somehow unique per item clicked and you want to be able to set the appropriate `label` instance when the timer elapses. In that case, you can use an anonymous method as the timer's event handler itself, capturing the `label` value and assigning it there:

```
void contexMenuuu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = ... something here?;
    var label = ... and something here?;

    if (item.Text == "Acknowledge")
    {
        label.Text = "NO";

        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => label.Text = "YES"));
        aTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).TotalMilliseconds;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Note that the above assumes that `label` is a local variable in the `contextMenuuu_ItemClicked()` method. In that case, the value is correctly captured (assuming it's not modified elsewhere in the method) for use in the timer event handler. If it's declared elsewhere, then you will need to declare a local variable, into which you copy the value of `label`, and use that local variable in the event handler anonymous method instead of `label` itself.